# aes_encrypt insert into table

Tags: mysql, password-encryption

my query is not work

`INSERT INTO rebuilder (id_utente, pwd)VALUES('75693',AES_ENCRYPT('password','set'))`

I haven't errors but the pwd value in DB table is NULL.

Ideas?
Tnx
Stefania

Comment: show you table definition please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf88bf/1)

```
create table rebuilder (
  id_utente int,
  pwd varbinary(200) 
);

-- data
insert into rebuilder (id_utente, pwd) 
values (75693,aes_encrypt('password','set'));
```

---

[image]

see [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf88bf/1)